# Calculating position of click in Rectangle

Tags: c#, vector, xna, position, monogame

I made a simple Tile map editor for 2d games.

Everything is working so far but there is a little ugly thing.

If I drag a Tile it drags from the (Top,Left) of the Tile but i want to drag it from the clicked position.

[image: picture of a tile]

> ```
> toDrag.hitbox.X  = ((int)cursorPos.X -(int)clickpos.X) + (int)campos.X;
>
> toDrag.hitbox.Y = ((int)cursorPos.Y -(int)clickpos.Y) + (int)campos.Y;
> ```

How can I calculate this?

Comment: What kind of code is that?  We don't know what your variables are because you only gave a short part of the code.

Comment: Hi, it's C# Xna/Monogame framework. I got it working Thank You all :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Brainarts suggested you have to take the offset of the cursor into account.

Some working code would look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        Rectangle myBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
        Point mouseDownPos = Point.Empty;
        bool allowMove = false;

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);

            if (!myBox.Contains(e.Location))
                return;

            mouseDownPos = new Point(e.Location.X - myBox.Left, e.Location.Y - myBox.Top);

            allowMove = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);

            allowMove = false;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!allowMove)
                return;

            myBox.Location = new Point(e.Location.X - mouseDownPos.X, e.Location.Y - mouseDownPos.Y);

            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aquamarine, myBox);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the offset of the cursor with the picturebox or rectangle, the difference is what you need to use to give the effect you want :)